# Is it right pattern of using Spring batch if one task that is launched through SCDF API call will launch other task through SCDF API calls?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a requirement to have a schedule batch that will identify what are the batches I need to restart or re-submit(as new job instance). Schedule batch will identify and call SCDF API to launch tasks. Is it really good design pattern to have a such batch ?

I can implement the above require pattern but is is good practice or anyone can suggest what is alternate way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong in implementing that requirement with Spring Batch (it would be a single step job with a simple tasklet). The  question you should be asking is that do you really need a Spring Batch job for that? What would you gain from using Spring Batch? Most interesting features won't be used for that job (restartability, fault-tolerance, transaction management, etc), so the benefit/cost ratio is low IMO.

I have seen folks putting similar logic (db query + rest call) in a shell script scheduled with crontab. And I see nothing wrong with this approach neither.

So it really depends on how you want to implement that requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, I understood your point.